# This application does not have the debuggable attribute enabled in its manifest

Tags: android, android-studio

Cannot debug application com.domain.test on device samsung-gt_i9300-323020cfc86b804f.
This application does not have the debuggable attribute enabled in its manifest.
If you have manually set it in the manifest, then remove it and let the IDE automatically assign it.
If you are using Gradle, make sure that your current variant is debuggable.

Comment: i got solution.  i changed build variant debug to release from android studio left corner

Comment: That isn't really a solution, just a work around. What attribute needs to be added to the build gradle to make it debuggable? Did you find out?

Comment: If you're getting this error with IntelliJ IDEA then you can take a look here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153902 But the current situation is that JetBrains acknowledges that it's a bug, but it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Try the below solution. It worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47960002/4675067

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Your comment has already hinted the answer to this post but since you have not selected an answer I'll write it down.

Change build variant from **release** to **debug** from android studio left corner.

[image: **Build variant** tab's default position in AndroidStudio]

Comment: And how exactly is this an answer?

Comment: @DebosmitRay The author had hinted to the answer instead of giving the answer, but the hint was very useful. Thanks for mentioning it, I changed the answer to exactly address the problem.

Comment: what is left corner? be more specific, make a screenshot please

Comment: @djdance, a left bottom corner, where a gray squere is drawn. It opens a menu, where you can find "Build variants".

Comment: that gray square just toggles tools. But what I need is in View/Tool window/Build variants.

Comment: @djdance, I have just checked your variant, it's the same. Click on a gray square in a left bottom corner. In the left you will see 2 tabs: "Favorites" and "Build Variants".

Answer (score 64):

A right solution is written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25628789/2914140:
open build.gradle of your module, type: 'debuggable true' (an example is below):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

When you generate a signed APK from menu, you should edit 'release' branch changing 'debuggable true' to false in order to avoid a debuggable information.

Answer (score 4):

In build.gradle

```
debug {
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for whose came here searching TS's quote, check if you set **Android Application** in Run/Debug configuration popup. Not Native, like in my mistake.

Comment: It's already an Android Application and not Native (but Java), but an error still exists.