# Android Studio will not debug (only builds) since trying to generate a signed apk

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

AS builds the debug APK just fine, but will not load to the phone and debug on the phone
Here is the output on a debug [assembleDebug] run:

```
7:52:18 PM: Executing task 'assembleDebug'...

Executing tasks: [assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageDebug
:app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
7:52:20 PM: Task execution finished 'assembleDebug'.
```

Note that it never attempts to install or debug...

Comment: I found the answer to my issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860720/this-application-does-not-have-the-debuggable-attribute-enabled-in-its-manifest

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and created a new project and copied over my files and it is working.